# Scheduled Scripts Params

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a scheduled script "A" containing parameters. I want to use these params in another scheduled script "B", knowing that I will execute the script "B".

I try calling the first script "A" from the script "B", but the result of the script "A" (`runtime.getCurrentScript.getParameter`), when I do save and execute of script "B" is undefined.

Thank you for your help, if there are other solutions thank you for mentioning :)

Comment: Show (the relevant parts of) your scripts so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the parameter's preference to Company.

[image]

Once the script parameter is set as a company preference you can retrieve it using:

```
var user = runtime.getCurrentUser();
var scriptParam = user.getPreference({
                    name: 'custscript_param_name'
                  });
```